# Floating point C++ compiler options | preventing a/b -> a* (1/b)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, optimization, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I'm writing realtime numeric software, in C++, currently compiling it with Visual-C++ 2008.
Now using 'fast' floating point model (`/fp:fast`), various optimizations, most of them useful my case, but specifically:

```
a/b -> a*(1/b) Division by multiplicative inverse
```

is too numerically unstable for a-lot of my calculations.

(see: [Microsoft Visual C++ Floating-Point Optimization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289157(VS.71).aspx))

Switching to `/fp:precise` makes my application run more than twice as slow. Is is possible to either fine-tune the optimizer (ie. disable this specific optimization), or somehow manually bypass it?

-
Actual minimal-code example: -

```
void test(float a, float b, float c,
    float &ret0, float &ret1) {
  ret0 = b/a;
  ret1 = c/a;
}
```

[my actual code is mostly matrix related algorithms]

Output: VC (cl, version 15, 0x86) is:

```
divss       xmm0,xmm1 
mulss       xmm2,xmm0 
mulss       xmm1,xmm0
```

Having one div, instead of two is a big problem numerically, (xmm0, is preloaded with 1.0f from RAM), as depending on the values of xmm1,2 (which may be in different ranges) you might lose a lot of precision (Compiling without SSE, outputs similar stack-x87-FPU code).

Wrapping the function with

```
#pragma float_control( precise, on, push )
...
#pragma float_control(pop)
```

Does solve the accuracy problem, but firstly, it's only available on a function-level (global-scope), and second, it prevents inlining of the function, (ie, speed penalties are too high)

'precise' output is being cast to 'double' back and forth as-well:

```
 divsd       xmm1,xmm2 
 cvtsd2ss    xmm1,xmm1 
 divsd       xmm1,xmm0 
 cvtpd2ps    xmm0,xmm1
```

Comment: Any floating point math that relies on equality will be unstable.

Comment: @Hans: OP isn't looking for equality; he/she's saying that the compiler is making the above substitution as an optimisation, and that this is unhelpful in his/her application.

Comment: @Oli: still, we don't know if OP's precision requirements are achievable or out of this world.

Comment: @peterchen: how can not replacing a division with a multiplication by the inverse be "out of this world"? Do re-read the first line of the actual question

Comment: @oyd11: How many significant digits do you lose by that optimization? How many significant digits do you need to be preserved for your calculation to be "ok"? Do you currently rely on the internal 80 bit precision? Numeric precision is complicated, If that optimization is really a problem, it's very unlikely (though possible) it's the **only** one.

Comment: @peterchen: The OP has implied that with /fp:precise, everything's fine.

Comment: @peterchen: the number of significant digits depends on the arguments, numerica precision is complicated, I'm aware of that, this is numerical software I'm writing here. I'm not using internal 80bit precision anywhere, as I'm using the SSE unit rather than the stack FPU. I have many numerical 'problems' in my code, by definition, as it's numerical. Most of them, less affected by optimization options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Weird) solution which I have found: whenever dividing by the same value in a function - add some epsilon:

```
    a/b; c/b
```

->

```
    a/(b+esp1); c/(b+esp2)
```

Also saves you from the occasional div by zero

Answer (score 3):

Add the

`#pragma float_control( precise, on)`

before the computation and

`#pragma float_control( precise,off)`

after that. I think that should do it.

Comment: yes, that's what I'm currently using:
#pragma float_control( precise, on, push )
...
#pragma float_control(pop)

unfortunately, it seems to work only on a whole-function level, plus prevent inlining. I'll add a comment with my current findings.
It would really rock, if there'd be a more fine-tuned float-optimisation option

Answer (score 2):

That document states that you can control the float-pointing optimisations on a line-by-line basis using pragmas.

Answer (score 1):

There is also __assume. You can use __assume(a/b != (a*(1/b))). I've never actually used __assume, but in theory it exists exactly to fine-tune the optimizer.

Comment: Good to know about __assume(), other compilers I have used before had similar options ( NASSERT in TI's compilers), will try that, however, I think the compiler already assumes (a/b != (a*(1/b)))

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the functions containing those calculations in a separate source code file and compile only that file with the different settings?

I don't know if that is safe though, you'll need to check !